# How do I solve Lintian errors when installing GitKraken.deb?

Tags: software-installation, deb, gdebi

Trying to install [GitKraken .deb](https://www.gitkraken.com/download) on Ubuntu16.04 I am getting the follow messages:`Unleash your repo`
[image]

On GDebi Package Installer I am getting the follow errors:

```
Litian Output
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 1
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of changelog-file-missing-in-native-package for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 2
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of copyright-file-contains-full-apache-2-license for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 3
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of copyright-should-refer-to-common-license-file-for-apache-2 for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 4
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of embedded-library for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 5
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of package-installs-python-bytecode for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 6
E: gitkraken: malformed-override Override of unstripped-binary-or-object for package type atom (expecting binary) at line 7
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken: srtp
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken: libpng
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken: sqlite
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken: libxml2
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken: lcms2
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken: libjpeg
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/libffmpeg.so
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/libffmpeg.so: libavutil
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/libnode.so
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/libnode.so: zlib
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/libnode.so: openssl
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/build/Release/system_idle_time.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/build/Release/system_idle_time.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/build/Release/findGitRepos.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/build/Release/findGitRepos.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/build/Release/keyboard-layout-manager.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/build/Release/keyboard-layout-manager.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/build/Release/keytar.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/build/Release/keytar.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node: zlib
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node: openssl
E: gitkraken: embedded-library usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node: libssh2
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/build/Release/nsfw.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/build/Release/nsfw.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/pathwatcher.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/pathwatcher.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/build/Release/runas.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/build/Release/runas.node
E: gitkraken: arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node
E: gitkraken: unstripped-binary-or-object usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node
E: gitkraken: missing-dependency-on-libc needed by usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken and 12 others
E: gitkraken: changelog-file-missing-in-native-package
E: gitkraken: extended-description-is-empty
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/bin/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: symlink-should-be-relative usr/bin/gitkraken /usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/applications/gitkraken.desktop 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/doc/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: extra-license-file usr/share/gitkraken/LICENSE
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/locales/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/7zip/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/7zip/7zip-lite/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/7zip/7zip-lite/7-zip.dll 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/7zip/7zip-lite/7-zip32.dll 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/7zip/7zip-lite/7z.dll 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/7zip/7zip-lite/7z.exe 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/build/Release/system_idle_time.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/build/Release/findGitRepos.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/build/Release/keyboard-layout-manager.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/build/Release/keytar.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/build/Release/nsfw.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/pathwatcher.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/build/Release/runas.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/src/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/src/THIRD-PARTY-LICENSES.txt 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: non-standard-dir-perm usr/share/lintian/ 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-executable-perm usr/share/lintian/overrides/gitkraken 0775 != 0755
W: gitkraken: non-standard-file-perm usr/share/pixmaps/app.png 0664 != 0644
W: gitkraken: binary-without-manpage usr/bin/gitkraken
W: gitkraken: executable-not-elf-or-script usr/share/lintian/overrides/gitkraken
E: gitkraken: shlib-with-executable-bit usr/share/gitkraken/libnode.so 0755
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@paulcbetts/system-idle-time/build/Release/system_idle_time.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/find-git-repositories/build/Release/findGitRepos.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keyboard-layout/build/Release/keyboard-layout-manager.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/keytar/build/Release/keytar.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-executable-stack usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/nsfw/build/Release/nsfw.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/pathwatcher/build/Release/pathwatcher.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/runas/build/Release/runas.node 0664
W: gitkraken: shlib-with-bad-permissions usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node 0664

Lintian finished with exit status 1
```

Any guess on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Not so much as a solution, but my first guess would be that might be installing the application as a non-root user (I don't use GDebi, so I don't know if that's even possible). That said--if it were me--I'd uninstall, and reinstall on command line (using `sudo dpkg -i Gitkraken.deb` or similar) and monitor any errors that procedure generates.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, gdebi calls lintian to check the .deb you are installing for "errors" or debian (packaging) policy violations.

So there are sort of two parts of this answer;

First, gdebi should have installed the gitkraken package (.deb) and it's dependencies.

So try gitkraken and see if it is working (and update your question).

---

The second part of this answer is some general information about lintian

Generally, in an ideal world, package maintainers would check their work, if you will, by running lintian and fixing any warnings / errors it throws.

For details see http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html#next-steps for details :

> Even if it builds the .deb binary package, your packaging may have
>   bugs. Many errors can be automatically detected by our tool lintian
>   which can be run on the source .dsc metadata file, .deb binary
>   packages or .changes file:

See also https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/checkit.en.html#lintians

> Run lintian(1) on your .changes file. The lintian command runs many
>   test scripts to check for many common packaging errors.
>   E: for error; a sure policy violation or packaging error.
>
> W: for warning; a possible policy violation or packaging error.
>
> I: for info; information on certain aspects of packaging.
>
> N: for note; a detailed message to help your debugging.
>
> O: for overridden; a message overridden by the lintian-overrides files but displayed by the --show-overrides option.

So , ideally, package maintainers would run lintian and "fix" any errors.

In practice , packages are not as "clean" as we would hope, or in the case of your gitkraken package there are many warnings.

If you wish more information you can google 'lintian non-standard-dir-perm' which would lead to this page

https://lintian.debian.org/tags/non-standard-dir-perm.html

> The directory has a mode different from 0755, and it's not one of the
>   known exceptions.
>
> Refer to Debian Policy Manual section 10.9 (Permissions and owners)
>   for details.
>
> Severity: normal, Certainty: possible
>
> Check: files, Type: binary, udeb

At least, that is how I personally look up lintian messages , you could use command line options, but I find the web pages more informative with links to Debian (packaging) policy.

As an end user you have 3 options:

- If the package installs and works you can *probably* ignore those messages, most users do.
- You could read all those policy violations and (manually) fix them (if possible) yourself post-install (major headache, very few people do this).
- File a bug report and ask the person who made the package to check their work. They may or may not do so.
- If the package does not install, you would have to file a bug report anyways, and including errors from lintian *may* help (not seen it but it might happen).

So , in summary, if the package works you can almost certainly ignore lintian output (which is what most people do).